# IOS: how to insert a filmStrip Type view in Main UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

i am working in a project in which i need to implement a `UICollectionView` which scroll horizontally inside my `UIView` to show the thumbnails of videos which when clicked video started play.
and my main `UIView` will scroll vertically.
please help me how i implement this into my project

i am sharing an example image with question take a look at image i want to implement the same in my project

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two collection views: one for the vertical scroll and one for the horizontal scroll.

For each UICollectionView You need to add a UICollectionViewFlowLayout that will it's behavior.

For the horizontal one you can look at HACollectionViewLargeLayout.m found here:

https://github.com/hebertialmeida/HAPaperViewController/blob/master/Paper/HACollectionViewLargeLayout.m